# How do I create command line menu in Debian with a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian, video, software-development

I have built a video wall out of raspberry pis and I am trying to create a menu in the command line for the master pi to select a video to play. Whats the easiest way to do that?

Comment: interesting, have you looked at menus using regular bash  scripts? 
btw how many pi's did you hook up for the pi-wall?

Comment: 9 pis as far as screens go, plus one for the master. Bash Scripts would be nice to use, but I havent really used much bash until starting this project, so I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Nice, what player are you using? 
Can you update the update the question with the command you are using?

Comment: How did you split the video out between different pis?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe have a look at [curses](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libncurses5-dev) or [dialog](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/dialog).

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to write the command line menu entirely by yourself. For example, if you are familiar with C/C++ you can use the system command and issue a "clear" in order to clear the screen in the output and present/refresh the new state of your menu. If you want to create something simple it is not a bad idea because you don't have to read anything about ncurses, etc.